# Get JRE version from System Property

Tags: java

It's not a duplicate. I would like to get current JRE version while program is executing.

To test result I've installed JDK 8.91 (without JRE 8.91 installation) and JRE 8.77. Also I've created JRE_HOME, JAVA_HOME variables, excluded Path variable with JDK folder.

My Tomcat uses JRE so I would like to get current JRE version before I will launch it. I found solution like:

```
System.getProperty("java.version")
```

After executing

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"))
```

I get result `1.8.0_91` Instead of `1.8.0_77`, which I wanted to get.

However, Oracle documentation gives the definition that this is JRE version.

Link:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29

How can I fix it?

Comment: A Java program *always* runs on a JRE (Java Runtime Environment). There's no such thing as a program running on a JDK. JRE version 8 update 91 is included with JDK 8 update 91. When you install the JDK, a JRE is always included. There's a `jre` directory in your JDK home dir.

Comment: @Jesper I understand that. While I was installing JDK I had an option to install JRE or not. Also I don't see JRE 8.91 as installed.

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly your question is. What doesn't work the way you expected and what do you want to fix?

Comment: When you install the JDK you get an option to install the **public** JRE, which is a separate JRE installation from the JDK. But even if you don't install the public JRE, there's still a JRE included in the JDK directory.

Comment: @Jesper That made it clear for me, thank you. post it as an answer please

Comment: In addition to what Jesper said: the _public_ JRE is only necessary for the dreaded browser plugin. So but not installing it you not only save space on your hard driver but also make sure you don't get the Java plugin

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thank you ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if I won't install public JRE, should i set JRE_HOME to jdk folder?

Comment: Yes, although most Java tools are looking for `JAVA_HOME` not `JRE_HOME` (I have never used `JRE_HOME` in 15 years)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a Java program, it always runs on a JRE (Java Runtime Environment). You cannot run a program on the JDK directly.

When you install Oracle's JDK, a JRE is included, you can find it in the `jre` directory in the JDK installation directory.

When you install Oracle's JDK, you get an option to install a "public JRE". This is a JRE that is installed separately from the JDK itself, and is used by browser plug-ins. You need this only if you want to be able to run Java applets in your browser.

Comment: Ummm, doesn't answer the question?